# Django QuerySet for latest and distinct

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class CarPrice(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

There can be multiple CarPrices for the same Car with different start_dates for the set price.

I need something that looks like:

```
car_prices = CarPrice.objects.filter(car__in=cars).get_latest()
```

How can I construct a query that returns a QuerySet with all the latest CarPrices (start_date < now) for each Car in cars (needs to be distinct for each car).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

car_prices = CarPrice.objects.filter(car__in=cars) \
    .annotate(latest=Max('car__carprice_set__start_date')) \
    .filter(start_date=F('latest'))
```

This will annotate each `CarPrice` object with the latest `start_date` for all prices related to the `CarPrice`'s car. Filtering on `start_date=F('latest')` will return only the latest object for each `Car`.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this works now. Just one comment: I got an error for 'car__carprice_set__start_date' saying that the field 'carprice_set' does not exist. I got it working though by using  'car__carprice__start_date' instead.

Comment: Apparently Django 1.6 introduced a new setting `related_query_name`, and the default for this is indeed `carprice`, not `carprice_set` as it was. Anyway, such confusion about the defaults is why I always specify a `related_name`. :)

Comment: Hmm, I am using Django 1.5 so it shouldn't be that? But it seems to do the right thing. Going to accept this as an answer. Thanks again.